# A good SATA raid card for Solaris

Tags: raid, solaris

Can someone recommend a good raid card for OpenSolaris (2009.6)? Requirements: 6-8 SATA ports, RAID5, preferable fanless (the server will be installed in the office environment).

p.s. please don't offer to use raidz. it's slow like any other software raid.

Answer (score 1):

I've used 3Ware (only 4-port) SATA cards on Windows, Linux and Xen so I can't comment on specifically OpenSolaris. I have yet to have an issue with them yet. The 8-port 3Ware 9650SE-8LPML "officially" supports OpenSolaris 2008.11 as stated [here](http://www.3ware.com/support/OS-support.asp#opensolaris). I realize the versions aren't quite a match, but I can't imagine it being too much of an issue unless 2009.6 is has changed radically.

You should also specific what bus (PCI, PCI-X, PCI-e, etc. etc.) you plan on installing the RAID card as different RAID card vendors tend to put different features on different buses. For example, 3Ware supports RAID 6 only on PCI-e x4 for 8-ports or more.

Comment: I have pci-e as well as pci-x on my board so I don't care about a bus. I like 3ware and know 9650SE support OpenSolaris 2008.11 but 3ware support is very skeptic about 2009.6. I will test it but it seems it is officially not supported neither by 3ware nor by Sun.

Comment: Well, Areca is another solid vendor in the SATA RAID market. I don't want to recommend *gambling* on a particular vendor's support but I'm not aware of many other vendors that offer such support for OpenSolaris.

Comment: Well, I suggest taking a look at the HCL from OpenSolaris here: http://www.sun.com/bigadmin/hcl/data/os/components/views/disk_controller_all_results.page1.html 
It mentions a lot more Intel, HP, LSI based controllers but not 3Ware directly. Take a look around the list but I would start here.

Answer (score 0):

I use the Areca 1220 and it seems to be well supported by Solaris.

Comment: what about a fan? is it loud?

Comment: The card itself isn't loud, but if you have have lots of hard drives they can be loud.  You'll also need to cool them which can add some additional noise.

Comment: we have a special enclosure system to cool 8 hdds with one 12" 1200rpm fan so that's no problem. all hdds are below 115F